# Mikrocontroller (PIC16F1827) ADC scrambled output with MCC in MPLAB

Tags: pic, mplab, mcc

Im trying to construct an AD-converter from a potentiometer to an Arduino. I´m trying to learn MCC in MPLAB at the same time. So far I have generated a code that fits my PIC (I think...). My problem is now that my bit represented output is incorrect. This is hoe my PIC16F1827 is configured (se picture) 
[image]

RA0 = input, RB1 and RB2 = EUSART and RB0,RB3,RA7,RA6,RB7,RB6,RB5,RB4 = output.

My main file look like this (se code). I get an output but its represented wrong and i can´t figure ut why...

```
char ADC_temp_in;
    while (1) //Infinite Loop
    {
        // Add your application code
        printf("pot_value =%d\r\n", ADC_GetConversion(channel_AN0_ADC));
        ADC_temp_in = ADC_GetConversion(channel_AN0_ADC);  // temp
        PORTB = ADC_temp_in;                  //Write Lower bits to PORTB
        PORTA = ADC_temp_in>>6;               //Write Higher 2 bits to PORTA
        __delay_ms(100);            //Delay     
    }
```

VREF+ = 5V and is connected directly to VDD.

My goal is to have RB0 as LSB and RA7 as MSB with the voltage difference 0-5 V with the potentiometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:
`ADC_temp_in` had to by a 16 Bit value to hold a value greater than 8 Bit.
So try: `uint16_t ADC_temp_in;`
Of course your function `ADC_GetConversion` had to return a `uint_16` value.

Another thing is, to get the MSB you had to shift your value 8 times right.

```
PORTA = ADC_temp_in>>8;
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for answering! I managed to fix the problem myself and i did exactly what you wrote.